# FluentValidation collection properties not validated

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

This is the first time I'm trying to implement FluentValidation since I need to cover a complex validation scenario.

The class I'm trying to validate has a large quantity of properties, complex objects and several collections.

I didn't have troubles to validate properties of the main class or even checking if collections are not empty, but I do have problems while validating objects properties within each collection.

To implement this I followed the examples documented here (check under "Re-using Validators for Collections"):
http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=creatingavalidator

These are my model classes (reduced to improve readability)

```
public class Caso
{
public int Id { get; set; } 
public string Descripcion { get; set; }
public List<Medicamento> Medicamentos { get; set; }
}

public class Medicamento
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Nombre { get; set; }
}
```

These are the validator classes:

```
public class CasoValidator : AbstractValidator<CasoAdverso>
{
    public CasoValidator()
    {
        RuleSet("Iniciar", () =>
        {
            // Validated OK
            RuleFor(x => x.Descripcion).NotEmpty();
            // Validated OK
            RuleFor(x => x.Medicamentos).Must(x => x != null && x.Count > 0).WithMessage("No puede iniciar un caso sin medicamentos cargados");
            RuleFor(x => x.Medicamentos).SetCollectionValidator(new MedicamentoValidator());
        });
    }
}

public class MedicamentoValidator : AbstractValidator<Medicamento>
{
    public MedicamentoValidator()
    {
        // NOT Validated. Even if the object property is empty the error message doesn't appear. I also checked using "NotNull" and "NotEmpty" clauses
        RuleFor(x => x.Nombre).NotNull().WithMessage("Debe especificar un nombre"); 
    }
}
```

(Note: I'm using RuleSet because of different validation schemas which are dependent of the document status in the workflow)

I'm executing the validation manually from the controller (no MVC integration)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Iniciar(Caso c)
{
    CasoValidator validator = new CasoValidator();
    FluentValidation.Results.ValidationResult validate = validator.Validate(c, ruleSet: "Iniciar"); 


    // ...
}
```

With this implementation properties of the main class are validated fine but I need also to validate each property of the "Medicamento" class within the collection.

Could I be missing something here?. Should this be validated using the RuleForEach clause available?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the RuleSet setting is applying to the child validator as well as the primary one.

I tested your code in an xUnit.net test, and confirmed it.

If you change your rulesets to execute you should find it works as expected:

```
CasoValidator validator = new CasoValidator();
FluentValidation.Results.ValidationResult validate = validator.Validate(c, ruleSet: "default,Iniciar");
```

The 'default' ruleset will work on the MedicamentoValidator rules.

I didn't find this in the documentation, only through testing.

This is the sample unit test:

```
[Fact]
public void Test1()
{

    Caso c = new Caso()
    {
        Id = 1,
        Descripcion = "none",
        Medicamentos = new List<Medicamento>()
    };

    c.Medicamentos.Add(new Medicamento()
    {
        Id = 0,
        Nombre= null
    });

    CasoValidator validator = new CasoValidator();
    FluentValidation.Results.ValidationResult validate = validator.Validate(c, ruleSet: "default,Iniciar");

    Assert.NotEmpty(validate.Errors);
}
```

Update: i found a reference by Jeremy Skinner for exactly this behavior:
http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/discussions/266920

> Rulesets cascade to any child validators, so whichever ruleset is
>   selected for use by the top-level validator will also be used by the
>   child validator. 
>        So if you ran the "Minimal" ruleset on the CreateProfileModelValidator, then only rules in the "Minimal" ruleset
>   will be run on *both* the CreateProfileModelValidator and the
>   ProfileValidator.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply. I've done your proposed adjustment and it is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

as a complementary:
a collection named GroupMemberIds should have AdminMemebrId:

```
RuleFor(r => new { r.GroupMemberIds, r.AdminMemberId }).Must(a => a.GroupMemberIds.Contains(a.AdminMemberId));
```