# FluentValidation - inner collection not validated

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

Have problem similar to [FluentValidation collection properties not validated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29379259/fluentvalidation-collection-properties-not-validated), unfortunately their fix does not work. Any ideas why underlying OrderValidator is not being involved?

```
validator.Validate(client, ruleSet: "Production");

public class ClientValidator : AbstractValidator<Client>
{
    public ClientValidator()
    {
        RuleSet("Production", () =>
        {
            RuleFor(client => client.Orders)
                .NotEmpty();

            RuleFor(client => client.Orders)
                .SetCollectionValidator(new OrderValidator());
        });
    }
}

public class OrderValidator : AbstractValidator<Order>
{
    public OrderValidator()
    {
        RuleSet("Production", () =>
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.Items)
                .NotNull();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give us an example instance of `client`?

Comment: @YannickMeeus: sorry, this question solved, but your help appreciated with my next problem :) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35291718/how-to-pass-ruleset-to-fluentvalidation-constructor

Answer (score 1):

Ok, Items.NotEmpty() should have been used instead of NotNull().